# Refresh Facebook Token iOS without leaving my app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Using the latest facebook login SDK, I'm wanting to generate a 'new and updated access token' from facebook without re-directing my app to facebook

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3


FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {if (error) { ...
```

Looks to Always redirect from my app to facebook, and back to my app again (even after my user has authorized my app to grab info from facebook)

For me it is not adequate to 'extend the life of my token' because the oAuth server I am using aggressively expires tokens every 5 minutes or so. Therefore I constantly need to request a new and updated access token from facebook every 5 minutes or so (and preferably without 'leaving my app to go to the facebook app, and then redirecting back to my app again.

Does the new facebook SDK have a function for this for ios?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'you can't'

Facebook forces you to redirect to their app to get a new token with new string characters - you can't get a new token while remaining inside your own app in iOS

Comment: who down-voted this answer and did not explain how this is possible?